# What is the name of this yellow / orange fungus?

Tags: species-identification, mycology

I've seen this in October 2016 on Corsica (Island of France):

[image]

I would guess each one is about 5cm - 15cm in diameter. Obviously, they come in small groups.

[image]

Comment: It would be nice to see how they look under the hat, and also the stem.

Comment: Do you have a picture of the stem or underside??

Comment: @theforestecologist No.

Answer (score 1):

Most fungi need to be studied under a microscope to determine a species. I think this belongs to the genus of [*Pholiota*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pholiota). I couldn't find an English name, if I translate the Dutch name, it would be **'Bundle mushroom'**. This name refers to the fact that they always grow in groups, usually on (dead) trees or trunks.

At first look thought this was a [Honey fungus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armillaria), but these are parasitic so usually don't grow on dead wood.

Comment: From the article you've linked: 'Because Armillaria is a facultative saprophyte, it also feeds from dead plant material, allowing it to kill its host, unlike parasites that must moderate their growth to avoid host death.'

Comment: Pholiota aurivella http://fieldguide.wardial.me/Mushroom%20pages/falllog.htm